# Use addProperty() on long links properly

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How can I use addProperty() on a long link to display a short link text?

Concretely I want to go from:

Link to company https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_Media_and_Entertainment

to:

Link to company [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_Media_and_Entertainment)

Is this possible in the property panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in property panel tries to detect property values that "look like URLs" and turn them into actual `<a>` links but it doesn't give you a way to give those links a different name.

In order to achieve what you want, you'd have to subclass the `ViewerPropertyPanel` class and override the `displayProperty` method that's responsible for turning a property record into actual HTML elements:

```js
displayProperty(property, parent, options) {
    const [nameEl, valueEl] = super.displayProperty(property, parent, options);
    if (property.value.startsWith('https://')) {
        valueEl.innerHTML = `<a href="${property.value}">Link</a>`;
    }
}
```

Here's a complete viewer extension that implements a custom property panel, incl. the link customization:

```js
class CustomPropertyPanelExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    constructor(viewer, options) {
        super(viewer, options);
    }

    async load() {
        this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.EXTENSION_LOADED_EVENT, (ev) => {
            if (ev.extensionId === 'Autodesk.PropertiesManager') {
                const ext = this.viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.PropertiesManager');
                ext.setPanel(new CustomPropertyPanel(this.viewer));
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    unload() {
        return true;
    }
}

class CustomPropertyPanel extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerPropertyPanel {
    constructor(viewer) {
        super(viewer);
    }

    displayProperty(property, parent, options) {
        const [nameEl, valueEl] = super.displayProperty(property, parent, options);
        if (property.value.startsWith('https://')) {
            valueEl.innerHTML = `<a href="${property.value}">Link</a>`;
        }
    }

    setProperties(props, options) {
        super.setProperties(props, options);
        this.addProperty('Prop A', 'https://forge.autodesk.com', 'Category 1');
    }

    setAggregatedProperties(props) {
        super.setAggregatedProperties(props);
        this.addProperty('Prop A', 'https://forge.autodesk.com', 'Category 1');
    }
}

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('CustomPropertyPanelExtension', CustomPropertyPanelExtension);
```

Comment: Thank you Petr, I'll mark this as complete and give your try out your extension.